# Indentation-Error is occurring and i can't seem to see what is making the error

Tags: python, livechat

I'm trying to make a live chat and after I'm done I get the Indentation-Error and the code down below is where the error is according to python.

```
    def recevied_message_from_server(self, so):
        while True:
          Buffer = so.recv(256)
          if not buffer:
              break
            message = buffer.decode('utf-8')
            if "joined" in message:
                user = message.split(": ")[1]
                message = user + " has joined"
                self.chat_area.insert('end', message + '\n')
                self.chat_area.yview(END)
            else:
                self.chat_area.insert('end', message + '\n')
                self.chat_area.yview(END)
        so.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to note here:

- after `break` statement, the indentation is a bit off
- there is a mix of 2 and 4 spaces

Check the below mentioned edited function once for reference:

```
def recevied_message_from_server(self, so):
    while True:
        Buffer = so.recv(256)
        if not buffer:
            break

        message = buffer.decode('utf-8')
        if "joined" in message:
            user = message.split(": ")[1]
            message = user + " has joined"
            self.chat_area.insert('end', message + '\n')
            self.chat_area.yview(END)
        else:
            self.chat_area.insert('end', message + '\n')
            self.chat_area.yview(END)

    so.close()
```

Comment: Thanks this also has hepled and fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have inconsistent number of spaces after the while loop, that is not allowed. :

```
    def recevied_message_from_server(self, so):
        while True:
            Buffer = so.recv(256)
            if not buffer:
                break
            message = buffer.decode('utf-8')
            if "joined" in message:
                user = message.split(": ")[1]
                message = user + " has joined"
                self.chat_area.insert('end', message + '\n')
                self.chat_area.yview(END)
            else:
                self.chat_area.insert('end', message + '\n')
                self.chat_area.yview(END)
        so.close()
```

Comment: i have to wait 5 min